# AfMotor Shield Library does not work with template programming

Tags: c++, arduino-motor-shield

I am able to move motors using AfMotor Shield Library. ( https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Motor-Shield-library )

Like :

```
AF_DCMotor insertionMotor(1);
AF_DCMotor pumpMotor(2);

void setup()
{
  insertionMotor.setSpeed(255);
  pumpMotor.setSpeed(255);
  insertionMotor.run(RELEASE);
  pumpMotor.run(RELEASE);
  insertionMotor.run(FORWARD);
  pumpMotor.run(FORWARD);
}
```

But if I want to write it like this, only the motor with the template expansion that I called last works.

```
enum class direction {
  FRW = 0x01,
  BCKW,
};

template<int n, direction type>
class Motor : public AF_DCMotor {

public:

  Motor() : AF_DCMotor(n) {
    setSpeed(255);
    run(RELEASE);
    run(type);
  }
};
Motor<1, direction::FRW> fanMotor;
Motor<2, direction::FRW> pumpMotor;
```

Only the pumpmotor is running. Or if I call the fanMotor after the pumpMotor, it still works.If I remove pumpmotor and leave only fanMotor, the fanMotor also works. Is there something I overlooked?

Answer (score 2):

Your code gives me a compiler error: in

```cpp
run(type);
```

the `run()` method expects a `uint8_t`, but it is given a `direction`.
Adding an explicit cast to `uint8_t` makes it compile.

Now, as a general rule, I would advice you to never touch the hardware
in a constructor. The problem is, if you create a global object (like
you are doing here), the constructor gets called before `main()`, thus
before the Arduino core has had a chance to initialize the hardware. If
your constructor touches any hardware register, this may conflict with
the initialization the core is going to perform right at the start of
`main()`.

The usual idiom for doing any hardware initialization is to define in
your object a method called `begin()`, and call it from `setup()`:

```cpp
template<int n, direction type>
class Motor : public AF_DCMotor {
public:
  Motor() : AF_DCMotor(n) {}

  void begin() {
    setSpeed(255);
    run(RELEASE);
    run((uint8_t) type);
  }
};
```

Comment: Yes you should do casting. (static_cast maybe more suitable). But it is not related about my problem.

Also with these lines, the constructor gets called before main()

AF_DCMotor insertionMotor(1);
AF_DCMotor pumpMotor(2);